# Making slider work on horizontal bar chart using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, slider

I want to built webpage which consist of 8-10 rows which expands when the slider is moved. so, basically it would be a slider on top and some rows underneath it - I want to move all the rows to expand or increase in size only width simultaneously when I move the slider. And to reduce when I move down the slider. Here is the code currently:

```
     $("#slider").slider({
    max: 850
});

$("#slider").slider({
    min: 30
});


$("#slider").slider({
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var selection = $("#slider").slider("value");
        console.log(selection);

        //Width and height
        var w = 500;
        var h = 50;

        //Data
        var dataset = [];

        dataset.push(selection);

        console.log(dataset);        

        var rectangle = svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset);

        rectangle
            .enter()
            .append("rect");

        rectangle.attr("height", 20)
            .attr("width", function (d) { console.log('d is ' + d);
            return d;
        })
            .attr("x", function (d) {
            return 20;
        })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
            return 20;
        });

        var w1 = 500;
        var h1 = 50;

        var dataset1 = [];

        dataset1.push(selection);

        console.log(dataset1);        

        var rectangle1 = svg.selectAll("rect1")
            .data(dataset1);

        rectangle1
            .enter()
            .append("rect");

        rectangle1.attr("height", 20)
            .attr("width", function (d) { console.log('d is ' + d);
            return d;
        })
            .attr("x", function (d) {
            return 20;
        })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
            return 50;
        });


        var w2 = 500;
        var h2 = 50;

        var dataset2 = [];

        dataset2.push(selection);

        console.log(dataset2);        

        var rectangle2 = svg.selectAll("rect2")
            .data(dataset2);

        rectangle2
            .enter()
            .append("rect");

        rectangle2.attr("height", 20)
            .attr("width", function (d) { console.log('d is ' + d);
            return d;
        })
            .attr("x", function (d) {
            return 20;
        })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
            return 80;
        });


    }
});

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be re-creating your rects on every slide event.  All you need is to change the width of those already there:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      $("#slider").slider({
        min: 100,
        max: 500,
        // on slide adjust width of all rects
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          svg.selectAll("rect")
            .attr("width", ui.value);
        }
      });

      // create svg
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 600)
        .attr("height", 600);

      // add 4 rects
      svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data([1, 2, 3, 4])
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d * 25;
        })
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("width", 100);
     
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for this working perfectly, is there any way to make the transition of each row with different transition rate and provide them with different minimum and maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider"></div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
 

var data = [ { rate:1.1, max:100 }, { rate:1.2, max:200 }, { row:1.3, max:300 }, { row:1.4, max:400 }];

$("#slider").slider({
    min: 100,
    max: 500,
    // on slide adjust width of all rects
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      svg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("width", function (d) {
             return Math.max(ui.value * d.rate, d.max);
        });
    }
});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```